# Best Way to Position ASP.NET Panels Side by Side

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm looking for the best solution to position two or more  containers side by side (left and right) as opposed to on top of eachother. I've looked up other posts and some say add style="float:left;" which is ok, others suggest adding style="display:inline;" which doesn't do anything. Is there a better suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `float` would be the preferred way.  What problem did you have?

Comment: Thank you! No problem, just on the edge of converting a legacy system to ASP.NET and before I create lots of pages I want use the best code so I don't have to go back and change things later.

Comment: there is not best solution. Is depend what you try to show and how.

Comment: Yeah, I am seeing that, I'm still stuck in the school of best solutions in the world of many ways. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this kind of style very often:

```
      .rightCol
  {
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
  }

  .leftCol
  {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: 10px;
  }
```

Define your own dimensions and you are good to go!

hope that helps!